# Connect WordPress blog to a Facebook account where I'm an administrator

Tags: facebook, wordpress

Say I'm an admin of Page X on Facebook, i.e. I can go to it and see:

> You are posting, commenting, and liking as Page X

and there's a button to go back to using my own account.

The WordPress Sharing settings have one simple button to "Connect to Facebook". If I click it, it offers to connect the WordPress blog to my own personal account, not Page X.

Is there any way to share WordPress/Facebook without logging out as me and logging in as Page X?

I don't have the login details at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this, for the record.

When you set the Sharing preference from inside your blog, i.e. at

yourblogaddress.com/wp-admin/

you have this problem. It doesn't ask which of your Facebook accounts/Pages you want to connect to.

But if you're at

wordpress.com/my-blogs/

and you click the Sharing link under your blog in the list, you get a dialog which identifies all the options and you can click the Page there to distinguish it from your own personal account.